# trivial Scala filter isn't trivial

Tags: scala

Okay, this *should* be a trivial problem, but I've been trying to make it work for hours.

I have a `List(Tuple2(String,Int) ... )`, with, for example, this data:

```
('PAUL ANKA',0)
('PAUL ANKA',0)
('P. ANKA /G. HAMILTON /J. NASH',0)
('PAUL ANKA',0)
('PAUL ANKA',0)
('PAUL ANKA',1)
('PAUL ANKA',0)
('PAUL ANKA',0)
('PAUL ANKA',0)
('PAUL ANKA',0)
```

I want to filter it for only the tuples with the second element == 1.

It seems trivial:

```
mylist.filter(_._2 == 1)
```

but no. So I tried

```
mylist.filter(x => x._2 == 0)
```

No joy. Each of these examples should result in a `List(('Paul Anka', 1))` but instead the list is empty.

This:

```
mylist.filter(x => true)
```

works as expected, ie, it's an identity.

I am tearing my hair on this.

Update:

Okay, this is interesting. The example list above is output from scala.

Using prayagupta's answer, I get

```
@ val data = List(("Charlie Martin", 99), ("prayagupd", 100), ("PAUL ANKA", 1))
data: List[(String, Int)] = List(("Charlie Martin", 99), ("prayagupd", 100), ("PAUL ANKA", 1))

@ println(data)
List((Charlie Martin,99), (prayagupd,100), (PAUL ANKA,1))
```

Observe that my example prints those strings (or putative strings) in single-quotes.

Comment: Why don't you add a type annotation to mylist when you set it (e.g. `mylist: List[Tuple2[String, Int]] = ...`) just to sanity check the type.

Comment: http://www.wartremover.org/doc/warts.html#equals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct but **make sure your initial data is correct and is of type `List[Tuple2[String, Int]]`**,

Try in scala REPL,

```
scala> val data = List(("Charlie Martin", 99), ("prayagupd", 100), ("PAUL ANKA", 1))
data: List[(String, Int)] = List((Charlie Martin,99), (prayagupd,100), (PAUL ANKA,1))

scala> data.filter{case (name, age) => age == 1 }
res1: List[(String, Int)] = List((PAUL ANKA,1))
```

alternative way,

```
scala> data.filter{_._2 == 1 }
res2: List[(String, Int)] = List((PAUL ANKA,1))
```

If you read the data from file or so, probably your data-structure is `List[(String, String)]` where `"1" == 1` is false,

```
scala> val data = List(("Charlie Martin", "99"), ("prayagupd", "100"), ("PAUL ANKA", "1"))
data: List[(String, String)] = List((Charlie Martin,99), (prayagupd,100), (PAUL ANKA,1))

scala> data.filter{_._2 == 1 }
res4: List[(String, String)] = List()
```

Comment: Bingo. I was being fooled by the aberrant way Scala displays this stuff. My entries were indeed `Tuple2[String,String]` -- I was sure I'd converted the second element to Int -- and the strings had single quotes around them because the strings did indeed have single quotes around them. In the string.

Answer (score 1):

Works just fine for me

```
val listOfTuples = List(("PAUL ANKA",0),
("PAUL ANKA",0),
("P. ANKA /G. HAMILTON /J. NASH",0),
("PAUL ANKA",0),
("PAUL ANKA",0),
("PAUL ANKA",1),
("PAUL ANKA",0),
("PAUL ANKA",0),
("PAUL ANKA",0),
("PAUL ANKA",0))

println(listOfTuples.filter(_._2 == 1))
```

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/uHxkL8C/0

Make sure your actual data isn't single quoting things.